# Setting current page link location?

Tags: php, html

I imagine this has been asked many times but I'm really not sure what I should be searching for.

Basically, I'm hosting a site which runs on PHP.
If on that site I add a page, lets say the page is `http://example.com/directory/page.php`,
then I add an anchor to that page, the link defaults to `http://example.com/#anchor`.

E.g.

```
<!-- http://example.com/directory/page.php -->
<a href="#anchor">Anchor</a>
```

Instead of then linking to:
`http://example.com/directory/page.php#anchor`,

it links to
`http://example.com#anchor`.

I don't especially want to have to echo the current page URL *every time* I add a non-external link, so what do I need to add to set the current page in PHP to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I have trouble believing that you are working for *United Online Web Services, Inc.*, please use `example.com` (or org or net) for example URLs. That is what the domain exists for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> so what do I need to add to set the current page in PHP to prevent this from happening

Nothing. You need (almost certainly) to **remove** the `<base>` tag.

Comment: Oh duh! Silly me! That's what you get for not commenting your month-old code and assuming it's not your own fault! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

try to use `<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>#anchor">Anchor</a>`

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `base` tag, and see if that solves your problem.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp